# How can I fix this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, api, file

I am trying to create an REST API and a part of the project requires working with JSON files.
I am trying to open a JSON file, to check whether certain content exists in the file. If it doesn't, it will be added. For that reason, I am trying to load the JSON file in order to use the dictionary methods. When I open the file and try to use the json.loads() function, I get an error. I am attaching the part of the code that doesn't work.

```
        file = open(self.storage_file_name, 'r')
        if file_is_empty:
            content_to_write = json.dumps(self.states_population_json, indent=4)
            file.write(content_to_write)
        else:
            current_date = str(date.today())
            print(file.read())
            json_content = json.loads(file.read()) # THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE APPEARS <<<
            if current_date in self.states_population_json["features"].keys():
                pass
            else:
                json_content["features"][current_date] = self.states_population_json["features"][current_date]
```

Here's the error as well:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried using json.load() instead of json.loads(), but then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Programming\ESRI_Internship\test_file.py", line 89, in <module>
    data.save_data_json()
  File "C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Programming\ESRI_Internship\test_file.py", line 79, in save_data_json
    json_content = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\denis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I made sure that the file isn't empty.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the content of the file (shortened a bit):

```
{
    "features": {
        "2022-01-06": [
            {
                "STATE_NAME": "Alabama",
                "POPULATION": 5028316
            },
            {
                "STATE_NAME": "North Carolina",
                "POPULATION": 10736879
            },
            {
                "STATE_NAME": "North Dakota",
                "POPULATION": 321419
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the (reduced, if too long) contents of the file? I suppose, that there is something wrong with the format in there.

Comment: I just added a shortened version of the file at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `print(file.read())` moves the file cursor for reading to the end of the file (the command reads the whole file). A subsequent `file.read()` thus will not be able to read anything. Just remove the `print` statement, or if needed, move the file cursor back to the beginning of the file by executing `file.seek(0)` before the `json.loads()` statement.

Comment: It worked! I don't need that specific print, but I do need some other operations earlier in the code, so I went with the file.seek(0) option. Thank you so much!